# Adding a button grid dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very basic MainWindow with a MenuStrip and 3 buttons in it, which looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to add a grid of buttons, but the grids size - the number of buttons - will change depending on which level the user chooses. Level 1 is a 5x5 grid, level 2 is a 7x7 etc. How can I add these buttons to the grid programatically? Currently I have:

```
<Window x:Name="medve_laszlo" x:Class="SavageMaci.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SavageMaci"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Medve László" Height="500" Width="700">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="1" Margin="38,0,187,430" Background="White">
            <Menu.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Menu.RenderTransform>
        <MenuItem Header="Level 1" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Level 2" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Level 3" FontFamily="Roboto" Height="32" Width="65"/>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've read an article [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Resources/676/how-to-create-a-grid-in-wpf-dynamically.aspx) about how to do it, and I'm trying to add the `DynamicGrid` described in the article to my own grid by

```
grid.Children.Add(DynamicGrid);
```

but this results in the DynamicGrid overlapping my menu. I'm planning on adding the elements based on the article via a loop if this works. Also, right now when launching the app I get two `MainWindow`s instead of one, not sure where that's stemming from, but if the error is in this piece of code, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

The code from the article is already adding the DynamicGrid to the window:

```
// Display grid into a Window
RootWindow.Content = DynamicGrid;
```

, but in your code you are adding it again by

```
grid.Children.Add(DynamicGrid);
```

Also in the article, the grid is not positioned anywhere specifically, not sure if WPF works differently, but in windows forms it will need a specific position.

Comment: I tried `RootWindow.Content = DynamicGrid;` but I got an error stating `The name 'RootWindow' does not exist in the current context`, so I guessed I'd add it to something that's existing. Can't I just somehow make it so that it doesn't overlap, without specific positioning data? Grids work like that most of the time.

Comment: i did not mean for you to add RootWindow.Content to your code. I was saying the article has that code and was not sure if you had removed it. I am now not sure what to say since I cannot see all your code.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ankgMG Here is the whole function, and the XAML is already in the question.

Comment: I mean, I should be able to have the menu in one cell of the grid and the `DynamicGrid` in another, right? I just don't know how to do it.